# Properties of the two ratios added

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $a,b,c,d$ are all positive integers with $\gcd(c,d)=1$ and

$$\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}=\frac{c}{d},$$ what can I say about the relationship between the factors of $a$ and $b$?

For example, if $1/x+1/y=2/5$, what can say about the factors of $x,y$? Or for a matter of fact what other non-trivial and significant things could I saw about $x,y$?

Comment: What are your thoughts? What have you tried?

Comment: In the example, 1/x+1/y=2/5, I gave the only thing I can deduce is that either x or y is a multiple of 5. Does anyone have anything else to conclude about the relationship between x,y, and 2,5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}=\frac{c}{d}$

$ab$ is the common denominator of the left hand side.
Make the denominators of the left hand side $ab$

It becomes:
$\frac{b}{ab}+\frac{a}{ab}=\frac{c}{d}$

Combining the fractions:
$\frac{a+b}{ab}=\frac{c}{d}$

If you have constant k:
$\frac{ka+kb}{kab}=\frac{kc}{kd}$
(Basically I multiplied both sides by 1)

The GCD is 1 so:
$k≤1$

But since

Does this help?